# Create back link user referer in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I've tried doing the following in my 404 error page to create a back link the referring page so that I don't have to rely on javascript.

```
<?php $this->set('refer', $this->referer()); ?>

<p><?php echo '<a href="'.$refer.'">Back to previous page</a>'; ?></p>
```

However it doesn't work... Any ideas why? This code is done in `/Errors/error404.ctp`

Comment: CakePHP doesn't seem to like referer being used outside of a controller... Any suggestions to get around this?

Comment: Interesting! There is a page in the book on [error handling and extending the exceptions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html), that seems like it might be a bit much to have to roll your own error handler just for this..

Comment: You're missing the point of the question. I'm not asking how to create an error page, rather how to display the referer in the view!

Comment: Which cakephp version are you using?

Comment: @cameron no I'm not, you can only get the referer method in the controller, and when you have a 404 the normal app controllers arent called, so you need to extend the current error controller in some way

Answer (score 14):

Use the request object :)

```
$this->request->referer();
```

Comment: Seems to be correct. http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-RequestHandlerComponent.html#_getReferer

Answer (score 3):

In CakePHP3 you can use:

```
<li><?= $this->Html->link(__('Back'), $this->request->referer()) ?></li>
```

It should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the beforeRender method of your app controller:

```
beforeRender() {
    $this->set('refer',$this->referer);
}
```

It should be available to all views then.

Comment: Tried that but looks like the beforeRender never gets called for the error pages :/

Comment: Are you sure you added it to AppController? This should work, CakeErrorController extends AppController

Comment: Think you should call this as a method and not as a property: $this->referer() instead of $this->referer

Answer (score 0):

What about using just  `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` instead? I know this is not the Cakey way to do it but it seems like it would work in your case.

Comment: Even though not the 'cake way' it worked well for me in CakePHP 1.3 in which the previous suggestions did not.

Answer (score 0):

$this->request->referer() works in .ctp file for **Cakephp version 2.8.0**
`<?php echo $this->Html->link(__d('user', 'Login', true), $this->request->referer(), array('class' => 'login_text'));  ?>`

Comment: This was already mentions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18754242/3749896)...